# Vue - Plugins won't Install

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vue-cli

I've tried to install the *Vue Router* and *Vuex* plugins, but the terminal simply stays like this indefinitely.

[image: Screenshot of terminal]

Vue is fully up to date and I'd tried reinstalling it, but to no avail.
I've also tried installing via the Vue UI but the same problem persists. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Terminal and open again and try this steps.
2. npm install vue-router
3. npm install vuex